# FTDI developer clip for metawatch firmware development

Tags: usb, firmware, ftdi, metawatch

I just got my metawatch package to play with. I am thinking to play with firmware on Linux as a hobby. But I am new to USB programming. So there is a starting rocky question from me.

The clip is a FTDI device. I browsed FTDI site, there are two types of driver: D2XX for direct access, and VCP (virtual COM port) driver to be used as a COM port.

My first plan is to see how to use one of the two drivers to write an app as firmware flasher.

My understanding is to flash firmware I need to use serial port to download the firmware to the watch. As the clip is acting as a media between pc and watch, I can't use D2XX APIs to flash firmware. VCP driver would be choice. Am I right about this?

Btw, would be any suggestion for starter to do usb/firmware programming?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the metawatch standard package clip comes with an FTDI device embedded in it allowing a serial port connection. So yes, you will need to install the VCP driver. This driver is built into the linux kernel. See the [installation guide](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/AppNotes/AN_220_FTDI_Drivers_Installation_Guide_for_Linux%20.pdf) for more information.

Sachi Murthy
Applications Engineer
FTDI Chip, USA